# Codeigniter Paypal IPN issue - It doesn't apply any settings after successful payment

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal, paypal-ipn

I've successfully implemented Ran's Paypal library and I am using the following Paypal IPN controller below. It works all correctly as far as I tested with Paypal sandbox. After payment I am clicking to return back to the merchant and the success code is appearing correctly. Just the IPN doesn't want to send any email, so I can verify that it works for 100%. Is there any issue on the IPN email sending function that may cause this behaviour?

Thanks!

```
<?php
/**
 * paypal_lib Controller Class (Paypal IPN Class)
 *
 * Paypal controller that provides functionality to the creation for PayPal forms, 
 * submissions, success and cancel requests, as well as IPN responses.
 *
 * The class requires the use of the paypal_lib library and config files.
 *
 * @package     CodeIgniter
 * @subpackage  Libraries
 * @category    Commerce
 * @author      Ran Aroussi <ran@aroussi.com>
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2006, http://aroussi.com/ci/
 *
 */

class Paypal extends Controller {

    function Paypal()
    {
        parent::Controller();
        $this->load->library('paypal_Lib');
    }

    function index()
    {
        $this->form();
    }

    function form()
    {
        $this->paypal_lib->add_field('business', 'demo@demo.com');
        $this->paypal_lib->add_field('return', site_url('paypal/success'));
        $this->paypal_lib->add_field('cancel_return', site_url('paypal/cancel'));
        $this->paypal_lib->add_field('notify_url', site_url('paypal/ipn')); // <-- IPN url
        $this->paypal_lib->add_field('custom', '1234567890'); // <-- Verify return

        $this->paypal_lib->add_field('item_name', 'Paypal Test Transaction');
        $this->paypal_lib->add_field('item_number', '6941');
        $this->paypal_lib->add_field('amount', '197'); 

        // if you want an image button use this:
        $this->paypal_lib->image('button_03.gif');

        // otherwise, don't write anything or (if you want to 
        // change the default button text), write this:
        // $this->paypal_lib->button('Click to Pay!');

        $data['paypal_form'] = $this->paypal_lib->paypal_form();

        $this->load->view('paypal/form', $data);

    }

    function auto_form()
    {
        $sessionid = $this->session->userdata('session_id') ; 

        $this->paypal_lib->add_field('business', 'demo@demo.com');
        $this->paypal_lib->add_field('return', site_url('paypal/success'));
        $this->paypal_lib->add_field('cancel_return', site_url('paypal/cancel'));
        $this->paypal_lib->add_field('notify_url', site_url('paypal/ipn')); // <-- IPN url
        $this->paypal_lib->add_field('custom', $sessionid); // <-- Verify return

/*      $this->paypal_lib->add_field('item_name', 'Paypal Test Transaction');
        $this->paypal_lib->add_field('item_number', '6941');
        $this->paypal_lib->add_field('amount', '197');   */

        $this->paypal_lib->add_field('cmd', '_cart');
        $this->paypal_lib->add_field('upload', 1); 

        /*$this->paypal_lib->add_field('item_name_1', 'Nokia N70');
        $this->paypal_lib->add_field('amount_1', 600);
        $this->paypal_lib->add_field('quantity_1', 5);

        $this->paypal_lib->add_field('item_name_2', 'Google Nexus One');  
        $this->paypal_lib->add_field('quantity_2', 1);
        $this->paypal_lib->add_field('amount_2', 800);*/

        $i = 1;
        foreach($this->cart->contents() as $key => $value)
        {
            $this->paypal_lib->add_field('item_name_'.$i, $value['name']);  
            $this->paypal_lib->add_field('quantity_'.$i, $value['qty']);
            $this->paypal_lib->add_field('amount_'.$i, $value['price']);
            $i++;
        }

        $this->paypal_lib->paypal_auto_form();
    }
    function cancel()
    {
        $this->cart->destroy(); 
        $this->load->view('paypal/cancel');
    }

    function success()
    {
        // This is where you would probably want to thank the user for their order
        // or what have you.  The order information at this point is in POST 
        // variables.  However, you don't want to "process" the order until you
        // get validation from the IPN.  That's where you would have the code to
        // email an admin, update the database with payment status, activate a
        // membership, etc.

        // You could also simply re-direct them to another page, or your own 
        // order status page which presents the user with the status of their
        // order based on a database (which can be modified with the IPN code 
        // below).

        $sessionid = '507';

        $data = array('users_logged_count' => 1);

        $this->db->where('users_id', $sessionid);
        $this->db->update('users', $data);     

        $data['pp_info'] = $_POST;

        $this->load->view('paypal/success', $data);
    }

    function ipn()
    {
        // Payment has been received and IPN is verified.  This is where you
        // update your database to activate or process the order, or setup
        // the database with the user's order details, email an administrator,
        // etc. You can access a slew of information via the ipn_data() array.

        // Check the paypal documentation for specifics on what information
        // is available in the IPN POST variables.  Basically, all the POST vars
        // which paypal sends, which we send back for validation, are now stored
        // in the ipn_data() array.

        // For this example, we'll just email ourselves ALL the data.
        $to    = 'tftestemail@gmail.com';    //  your email

        if ($this->paypal_lib->validate_ipn()) 
        {
            $body  = 'An instant payment notification was successfully received from ';
            $body .= $this->paypal_lib->ipn_data['payer_email'] . ' on '.date('m/d/Y') . ' at ' . date('g:i A') . "\n\n";
            $body .= " Details:\n";

            foreach ($this->paypal_lib->ipn_data as $key=>$value)
                $body .= "\n$key: $value";

            // load email lib and email results
            $this->load->library('email');
            $this->email->to($to);
            $this->email->from($this->paypal_lib->ipn_data['payer_email'], $this->paypal_lib->ipn_data['payer_name']);
            $this->email->subject('CI paypal_lib IPN (Received Payment)');
            $this->email->message($body);   
            $this->email->send();
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: The IPN is sent irregardless of pushing the 'back' button as far as I know, are your logs showing that the IPN is sent? remember you need to allow IPN from your paypal account aswell

Comment: I am using Paypal sandbox and testing with demo@demo.com Paypal account as merchant. I don't own it. Do I have to create merchant account in Paypal sandbox for that too? I only have one for making the fake purchase as test to demo@demo.com

Comment: I havn't dealt with paypal in a long while, but I remember having an option to register as a developer https://developer.paypal.com/ - you can create your own `fake` merchant account, and a buyer account. in the merchant account itself is where you setup the IPN url and such, take my words with a grain of salt as it's been a while :)

Comment: I just did that. And tested it fully. Paypal simply doesn't send IPN notifications. I checked from merchant account IPN history and no IPNs sent. Whats possible to cause that?

Comment: last thing I can think of, and sorry i'm not much help, is to make sure you've activated the IPN option in the merchant account, as I'm guessing the entire transaction works fine, but it just doesn't notify.

Comment: Yes, it is activated. Simply Paypal doesn't send any IPN notifications. IPN history in the business account is empty even when I tried at least 10 times ... something may cause it on my side but i dont know which code could do that ...